# Unescaping string in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

Google Book Search Give Output Something like this

```
Introducing Little Simon&#39;s new Baby Snoopy line, featuring Charles Schulz&#39;scharacters as babies.
```

How do i convert this into normal readable string ?

I tried URI.unescape and searched it online , but couldn't find anything. I am a newbie in Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you need to tell Rails that it's HTML safe.....

controller

```
@str = get_str_from_google_book_search(ie.your.string)
```

view

```
<%= @str.html_safe %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape that string. The following works just fine.

```
irb(main):001:0> s="Introducing Little Simon's new Baby Snoopy line, featuring Charles Schulz'scharacters as babies."
=> "Introducing Little Simon's new Baby Snoopy line, featuring Charles Schulz'scharacters as babies."
irb(main):002:0> s
=> "Introducing Little Simon's new Baby Snoopy line, featuring Charles Schulz'scharacters as babies."
```

If you had a character you needed to escape, such as ", you could escape it with a \ as so:

```
irb(main):008:0> s = "a\"b"
=> "a\"b"
irb(main):009:0> puts s
a"b
=> nil
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question I am getting this data from somewhere else , I am not adding this data by hand.

Comment: Right, I believe the exact issue here is the numeric character references; the general issue is any HTML markup. I've edited the question so you can see the reference.

Answer (score 0):

The string is already HTML, and you are working in Rails, so I'm not sure that you really need to boil it down further.  While the HTML numeric character references in your example string *do* have both ASCII and Unicode equivalents, anything more complicated like `<p>` will cause trouble.

However, for your example string, there is a way.

You can use an HTML parser to parse the string as a fragment.

```
require 'nokogiri'
s1 = 'How&#39;s life?'
s2 = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(s1).to_s
puts s2
```